# Designing an experiment to test before vs. after unsuccessful payment percentage

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, small-sample

I'm working at an online payment processor, which is used by multiple vendors (kind of like paypal). The experiment that I'm working on involves just one vendor. I have 100k data points from that vendor (each data point corresponds to a transaction - whether it was successful or not) collected over a period of past 7 days.

There's a limit to the number of transaction data I can ask the vendor to give each day, so I have to decide that. To do so, I have to have a target statistical power of the experiment at a given level of significance. To back-calculate sample size from stat power and significance level, I need to know what statistical test I'll be conducting.

The question I'm trying to answer is this: after a change done on our backend, will the unsuccessful transaction % increase, decrease or stay the same compared to the current 10%?

---

I'm confused because if I had a lot of days' data for that vendor, I could probably use the independent samples t test. Like so

Sample 1 (before backend change): Day $1$: $x_1\%$, Day $2$: $x_2\%$, $\ldots$, Day $m$: $x_m\%$ where $x_i\%$ is the unsuccessful transaction % on day $i$ (pre-change).

Sample 2 (after backend change): Day $1$: $y_1\%$, Day $2$: $y_2\%$, $\ldots$, Day $n$: $y_n\%$ where $y_j\%$ is the unsuccessful transaction % on day $j$ (post-change).

But of course there will be limited number of days of data for any vendor since realistically we can't wait for 30 (so that sample 1's size is good enough for the t test) days before making changes or taking action.

---

With the above background, I'd be really grateful for guidance on how to go about designing this experiment - i.e. what test to use and how to find out what number of transactions data I would need each day.

Comment: To clarify, does it has to be a before vs after test? Is it possible to configure your system backend such that e.g. half the transactions go through the old logic and half go through the new logic, or transactions that originate from a region go through the old logic and those originating from other regions go through the new logic? // Qualitatively, how stable are your unsuccessful transaction % across days when you say "current 10%"? Do they follow some sort of seasonality or events?

Comment: Moreover, does your backend change affect other vendors, and whether the other vendors will be able to provide similar transaction data?

Comment: agree with all @B.Liu 's points. but in addition if you are talking 100,000 datapoints in 7 days, even 1 day is likely sufficient[ but need to consider whether days are different - eg weekend vs weekday]. I would suggest use chi squared test: https://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mb55/yh_stats/chiodds.htm#:~:text=The%20chi%2Dsquared%20test%20works,there%20were%20absolutely%20no%20association.&text=Similarly%2C%20the%20proportion%20who%20refused,the%20null%20hypothesis%20were%20true.

Comment: @B.Liu : That's a very good point. Sorry I should've mentioned it. So the unsuccessful trx % is more or less stable except for days when there could be a issue with one of the bank infrastructure, but those are relatively uncommon events. As for your second question, the plan is the flow around 20% of trx through new logic initially - to see how it's doing, etc. And then in the next step to flow ~50% of trx through the new logic. Only then will full-scale adoption of new logic be considered.

Comment: Given you are planning to flow 20% of the transactions through the new logic initially, is it possible for you to randomly allocate which transaction goes into the 20%  and simply compare the % of unsuccessful transaction within the 20% (new logic) to that within the 80% (existing logic)? This allows you to use a simple proportion test (or t-test approximation given your sample size) using all the data you have as you are now running a simple randomised controlled trial, instead of relying on before vs after setup that can quickly become convoluted.